# How to create xpath for the element

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to the selenium usage for the web scraping.  I would like to create the xpath for my element to execute

"onclick="clearwsInfo('2015011800017','2015011800017',this);"
added complete html code below

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='../../accidentweb/interface/DwrUtilsDao.js'></script>
    <script src='../../accidentweb/engine.js'></script>
    <script src='../../accidentweb/util.js'></script>
   <base href="http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=GBK">
    <LINK href="css/css.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
    <title>Functional Query results</title>
    </head>
    <body bottomMargin=0 leftMargin=0 topMargin=0 >
 <TABLE  border="1"  bordercolorlight="#6D6D6D" cellspacing="1"
      bordercolordark="#C0C0C0" width="120%"
             cellpadding="0"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class=font9  style="BORDER-        bottom: #4D5E8C 1px solid" >
  <tr  bgcolor="#CCCCCC"     > 
      <td  class="title_1" width ='6%' align="center">department</td>
      <td  class="title_1" width ='6%' align="center">case number</td>   
      <td  class="title_1" width ='10%' align="center">time of accident</td>
      <td class="title_1" width ='20%' align="center">location of scene of accident</td>
      <td class="title_1" width ='6%' align="center">operator</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="cursor:hand" 
      onmouseover="onmouseoverTR(this)" 
      onmouseout="onmouseoutTR(this)"         
      onclick="clearwsInfo('2015011800017','2015011800017',this);"
      ondblclick='doSelect("auditflowForm","2015011800017");'> 
   <TD  align="center">
    <script type="text/javascript" >                               
                            outprint('FoShan Branch');                               
        </script>   
   </TD>
   <TD  align="center">
    <script type="text/javascript" >                               
                            outprint('4406150001');                              
        </script>   
   </TD>
   <TD  align="center">
    <script type="text/javascript" >                               
                            outprint('2015-01-09 11:00');                                
        </script>
   </TD>
   <TD  align="left">
      <script type="text/javascript" >                             
                            outprint('佛山市南海区大沥镇广佛路大镇加油站路口');                                 
        </script>
   </TD>
    <TD  align="left">
      <script type="text/javascript" >                             
                            outprint('陈三林');                                 
        </script>
   </TD>  
   </TR>


     <script anguage="javascript" >
      //clearwsInfo("2015011800017","2015011800017","");
    </script>


</TABLE>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried the below way but I got the error

```
 chromedriver = 'C:\Users\VM82958\Desktop\IE\IEDriverServer.exe'
 browser = webdriver.Ie(chromedriver)
 tr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/TABLE/tr')
```

error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\surendra\Neon-WorkSpace\EvidenseData\selinum.py", line 26, in    <module>
    tr = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/TABLE/tr')  #Post Parents Element of the element you want to click for more help (If you dont know how to use XPath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",   line 752, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find  element with xpath == //html/body/TABLE/tr
```

Comment: Is it main document or it's `iframe` content?

Comment: Could you try my answer? Please tell me if it works or not.

Comment: @ Simon Baars I tried but got an error.

Comment: @Andersson no Iframe its a document

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal HTML document instead of an arbitrary snippet of HTML. Also make sure you include all the code to reproduce the problem. Thanks. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Mathias Müller I added complete html in the question

Answer (score 0):

change the `TABLE` to `table` lowercase, there maybe some parse process to convert the tag name to lowercase.

Comment: `XPath` as well `HTML` is case insensitive. I mean for tags :)

Comment: @Andersson No, that's not true. HTML is case-insensitive, but XPath is not.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, I'm quite sure that `//TABLE/TR` will return same result as `//table/tr`...

Comment: @Andersson As far as XPath as a standard is concerned, no - it definitely won't return the same results. Perhaps the Selenium framework deals with HTML and XPath in a special way though.

Comment: @Andersson  in `lxml` upper case will be converted to lower case, I tested in it, it's not the same.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, yes, maybe it's just a `selenium` feature. Thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wait some time for table complete rendering:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


ie_driver = 'C:\Users\VM82958\Desktop\IE\IEDriverServer.exe'
browser = webdriver.Ie(ie_driver)
browser.get(URL)
tr = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tr")))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using `/html/body/TABLE/tr` ? note the single slash instead of double slash.. you're using the absolute xpath anyway.

but i think Andersson's answer is correct..wait for it to load first as well.